# loop in simplexml load file

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I am using the following code to parse the XML data to MySQL table and it is working as expected.

```
<?php
$sxe = simplexml_load_file("$myfile");
foreach($sxe->AUTHAD as $sales) {

$authad="insert into test.authad values ('".mysql_real_escape_string($sales->LOCALDATE)."','".mysql_real_escape_string($sales->LOCALTIME)."','".mysql_real_escape_string($sales->TLOGID)."','" ...

?>
```

The problem is that when I get a new xml file with different format, I can not use the above insert into statement and have to change the parameters manually. For e.g.

```
$authadv_new="insert into test.authad values ('".mysql_real_escape_string($sales->NEW1)."','".mysql_real_escape_string($sales->NEW2)."','".mysql_real_escape_string($sales->NEW3)."','" ...
```

Is there any way to automate this? I mean the PHP code should be able to anticipate the parameters and generate the mysql_real_escape_string($sales->NEW1) to NEW10 values using a loop.

Comment: NEW1, NEW2, NEW3 can be anything! I do not know. I want the code to find it out.

Comment: Can you put an example of you XML (to have the structure) ?

Comment: This code is ugly and unreadable. Use sprintf() at the least.
**$authad = sprintf('insert into \`test\`.\`authad\` values ("%s", "%s", "%s")',
mysql_real_escape_string($sales->LOCALDATE),
mysql_real_escape_string($sales->LOCALTIME),
mysql_real_escape_string($sales->TLOGID));**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While satrun77's example works fine, you can use slightly less code and stick to the advantages of the simplexml object by using its "children()" method:

```
$sxe = simplexml_load_string($xml);
foreach($sxe->AUTHAD as $sales) {
        foreach ($sales->children() as $child) {
                $children[]="'".mysql_real_escape_string($child)."'";
        }
        $authad="insert into test.authad values (".implode($children,",").");";
}
```

Comment: There are multiple files to be processed and the insert into tbl statement generated by satrun77's code works as expected. In your case, the code works for the first file. It then generates a single insert into statement for all the data from the second file onwards, which fails for obvious reasons.

Comment: Are you saying that this code is part of a larger loop that goes over many files consectutively? If so, then my code fails because I didn't initialize the $children array in my foreach subloop as satrun77 did above (but don't blame me .... I didn't understand how you were processing multiple files). If you add in "$children=array();" as the first statement inside the first foreach loop, it should work as well. But as I said, this is just a different strategy to accomplish the same thing; satrun77 uses the object as key/value pairs, I use the children() method ... both ought to serve your needs

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this using a dynamic variable `$var`?

```
<?php
$values = array();
for($i = 1; $i < 11; $i++) {
    $var = "NEW".$i;
    $values[] = "'".mysql_real_escape_string($sales->$var)."'";
}
$string = join(",", $values);
```

Comment: It has created 10 blanks like # '','','','','','','','','',''

Comment: Are the values you are looking for really named NEW1, NEW2 and so on? If not you would ofc need to adapt the script? (Assuming you pasted your simplexml_load_file stuff into the script before executing of course :) )

Answer (score 1):

I hope this is what you are looking for?

```
$string = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
<root>
   <AUTHAD>
      <NEW1>New 1</NEW1>
      <NEW2>New 2</NEW2>
      <NEW3>New 3</NEW3>
      <NEW4>New 4</NEW4>
      <NEW5>New 5</NEW5>
      <NEW6>New 6</NEW6>
   </AUTHAD>
   <AUTHAD>
      <NEW1>New 11</NEW1>
      <NEW2>New 22</NEW2>
      <NEW3>New 33</NEW3>
   </AUTHAD>
</root>
'; 

$sxe = simplexml_load_string($string);
foreach($sxe->AUTHAD as $sales) {
    if (count($sales) > 0) {
        $values = array();
        foreach($sales as $key => $sale) {
            $values[] = "'" . mysql_real_escape_string($sale) . "'";
        }
        $authadv_new="insert into test.authad values (" . join(', ', $values) . ")";
        echo $authadv_new.'<br >';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for `get_object_vars()` to iterate over the object members:

```
<?php

mysql_connect( 'localhost', 'root', 'moin' );

$sxe = simplexml_load_file( $argv[1] );
var_dump( $sxe );

$sql = "insert into test.authad values (";

foreach($sxe->AUTHAD as $sales) {
    $members = get_object_vars( $sales );
    $values = array();
    foreach ( $members as $name => $value ) {
        echo "$name : $value\n";
        $values[] = "'" . mysql_real_escape_string( $value ) . "'";
    }
    $sql .= join( $values, ', ' );
}

$sql .= ")\n";
echo $sql;
```

The input is this file:

```
<sxe>
    <AUTHAD>
        <eins>one</eins>
        <zwei>two':-)</zwei>
        <drei>three;"'</drei>
    </AUTHAD>
</sxe>
```

I'm getting the following result here:

```
insert into test.authad values ('one', 'two\':-)', 'three;\"\'')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're not concerned about the order of data between each XML you can just implode the object rather than pick out the specific values each time. Doing an implode also allows you to avoid the loop.

`INSERT INTO test.authad VALUES('".implode("','", mysql_real_escape_string($sxe->AUTHAD))."')`